# python: cannot get final return

Tags: python, return

declaration: this is an assignment. i've tried different combinations to move the variable [totalExposure] inside my code to get the return but failed.
question: find radiation exposure within a period of time by using recursion. 
problem: i can get all the calculations correctly [i checked it in online python executor] but when the process comes tothe final return, the result is [none]. i don't know why my code can't return the final calculation result. 
wish: some guru out there can give me some clues thanks.

```
global totalExposure
totalExposure=0 

def f(x):
    import math
    return 10*math.e**(math.log(0.5)/5.27 * x)

def radiationExposure(start, stop, step):

    time=(stop-start)
    newStart=start+step

    if(time!=0):
        radiation=f(start)*step
        radiationExposure(newStart, stop, step) 
        global totalExposure
        totalExposure+=radiation   
    else:
        return totalExposure
```

Comment: Add `return` before the recursive call as well: `return radiationExposure(newStart, stop, step)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to perform the recursion you must return the call in `radiationExposure`:

```
return radiationExposure(newStart, stop, step)
```

Comment: Wow that's quick and sound. problem solved. thank you very much

Comment: also you don't need any global here.

Comment: will be happy to know how to do that. in fact i tried not to using global variable but i can't get the accumulated result and always get the unbound error. wherever i move the totalExposure variable, it always start with the initialised values, i.e. 0. and return the result of the last recursion. in other assignments, i had the same problem about the scope of variable.